# Getting jQuery.browser is deprecated error in console magento 2.1.5

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, jquery

I keep on getting this error in my console,

```
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated
migrateWarn @ jquery-migrate.js:41
get @ jquery-migrate.js:58
(anonymous) @ jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js:9
(anonymous) @ jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js:9
(anonymous) @ jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js:9
jquery-migrate.js:43 console.trace
migrateWarn @ jquery-migrate.js:43
get @ jquery-migrate.js:58
(anonymous) @ jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js:9
(anonymous) @ jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js:9
(anonymous) @ jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js:9
```

[image]

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

`jquery-hashchange` is quite old, latest release is from 2010.

If you read the [README](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange) you will find that it supports jQuery versions:
`1.2.6, 1.3.2, 1.4.1, 1.4.2`
while Magento uses a newer version.

Just don't use it!